# SSIS convert source table into multiple data flow tasks that insert into same destination table

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012, ssis-2008

I have to migrate data from informix database to sql-server database. I'm using ssis packages for that transformation.
Informix database have tables that contain million of records.So, when i execute the ssis package that do transformation , it takes hours to complete.

I read about parallel fashion that would execute multiple tasks together, and it somehow reduces my time.

But real challenge is there as if i have to migrate a table that contain 50 million records then only one data flow will be there to convert it. So parallelism doesn't help me there.

Is there any way with which i can split source table into multiple data flow tasks that insert data into the same destination table.

Any thoughts/suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Balanced Data Distributor** Transformation [balanced-data-distributor-transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/balanced-data-distributor-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)
to increase your package speed, but this component **depends on your server resources**.

[image: Balanced Data Distributor]

Or you can split you're migrating table to several **source component** and for each source, create a query with increment load on the where clause (like date)and then use **UNION ALL** component to combine all the sources.

[image]

Comment: The balanced distributor is the way to go.  Keep in mind that indexing on the destination table can cause contention.  Ideally there will be no indexes (a heap), in which case use the TABLOCK hint on the destinations for minimal logging.

Comment: Never seen the Balanced Data Distributor transform before +1